# Optimizing reading integers directly into a set without a list comprehension in Python

Tags: python

I am reading space separated integers, removing redundant ones and then sorting them. The following code works.

I was thinking whether this is the fastest way to do that or can it be optimized more?

```
import sys

def p():
    #Reads space seperated integers
    #Removes redundant
    #Then sorts them
    nums = set(map(int,next(sys.stdin).split()))
    nums = [i for i in nums] -
    nums.sort()
    print nums
```

EDIT:

tobia_k's suggestion is better performance-wise. Just 1 sentence instead of 3 and better in time-efficiency.

```
nums = sorted([int(i) for i in set(next(sys.stdin).split())])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inpt = raw_input("Enter a string of numbers: ")
numbers = sorted(set(map(int, inpt.split())))
print numbers
```

- I would recommend separating the input-reading from the integer-extraction part.
- Using `raw_input` (Python 2.x) or `input` (Python 3) is more usual for reading user inputs.
- You can do it all in one line using `sorted` instead of `sort`.
- Performance-wise it *might* be better to apply `set` first, and then `map`, so `int` has to be applied to fewer elements, but I don't think it makes much of a difference, if at all.

Comment: I am working with online judging so performance matters a lot. I merged the reading and extraction part because they have slight overheads(not much but there are overheads). `raw_input` and `input` are very slow compared to this method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023170/what-are-other-options-for-faster-io-in-python-2-7. Applying set first was better